# How to plot relative proportions in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a df like this.

```
> te1.m.comb
   temp                variable     value
1    35      Light.180.1.x.MAX1 10.398333
3    35       Dark.180.1.x.MAX1 -4.337142
5    35      Light.288.5.x.MAX3 17.825376
7    35       Dark.288.5.x.MAX3 -4.331998
9    35         Light.D125.x.K1 15.150205
11   35          Dark.D125.x.K1 -4.376553
13   35 Light.SO443WL.x.SO479WL 11.003542
15   35  Dark.SO443WL.x.SO479WL -3.216878
17   35 Light.SO450WL.x.SO465WL 15.970640
19   35  Dark.SO450WL.x.SO465WL -3.109330
21   35 Light.SO459WL.x.SO469WL 11.393617
23   35  Dark.SO459WL.x.SO469WL -3.857454
2    40      Light.180.1.x.MAX1  8.589651
4    40       Dark.180.1.x.MAX1 -5.569157
6    40      Light.288.5.x.MAX3 15.977499
8    40       Dark.288.5.x.MAX3 -5.582502
10   40         Light.D125.x.K1 13.651815
12   40          Dark.D125.x.K1 -5.243391
14   40 Light.SO443WL.x.SO479WL  8.518077
16   40  Dark.SO443WL.x.SO479WL -4.861841
18   40 Light.SO450WL.x.SO465WL 13.691814
20   40  Dark.SO450WL.x.SO465WL -4.514559
22   40 Light.SO459WL.x.SO469WL  9.262019
24   40  Dark.SO459WL.x.SO469WL -5.138836
```

I would like to plot the relative proportions using ggplot. For example, instead of plotting each of the variable and its value, i would like to plot the ratio value of `Light.180.1.x.MAX1 / Dark.180.1.x.MAX1` i.e `10.398333/-4.337142` and so on. How can i do that in ggplot?

Here is my boxplot code which just plots each of the variable and its value..

```
ggplot(te1.m.comb, aes(variable, value)) + geom_boxplot() + facet_grid(temp ~.)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I renamed your `data.frame` `df` so that the reading can be easy and added the ratio column:

```
df$ratio = with(df, c(value/c(value[-1],NA)))
```

Here is the plot:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(variable, ratio)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  facet_grid(temp~.) + ¨
  scale_y_reverse()
```

[image]